# How to know if an element matches every in another table in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following problem in SQL:

I have a table with only 1 column containing different values: [A, B, C, D] for example

And in other table I have 2 columns with:

```
1 | A
1 | C
2 | D
1 | B
2 | D
1 | D
...
```

I need to return 1, because is the only item that matches every value in the other table, how do I do this? Thank you :)

Comment: Are values in table 2 unique? And what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the solution , you compare number of  rows in your second table with number of rows in your first table,
I'm using distinct to make sure if there is a duplicate it wouldn't be counted:

```
SELECT id 
FROM 
table2 
WHERE word in (select word from table1)
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT word) = ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation:

```
select col1
from table1 t1
where col2 in (select col2 from table2)
group by col1
having count(*) = (select count(*) from table2);
```

This assumes that the `col1`/`col2` columns are unique in `table1`.  If not, use `count(distinct)` in the `having` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option is to use `left outer join` and analytical function as follows:

```
Select id, word from
(Select t2.*,
       Count(distinct t1.word) over () as total_words,
       Count(distinct t2.word) over (partition by t2.id) as total_words_per_id
  From table1 t1
  Left Join table2 t2 on t1.word = t2.word)
Where total_words = total_words_per_id
```